# How to write own map generator?

Tags: python

I would like to write for myself a simple map generator and I do not know how to bite. field will have to draw lots hexagonal.

When I generate random tile I must watch for neighbor. Then I have to take into account the already two neighbors, etc. Recursion? I determined that the field may be the water, the earth, the mountains - but in one field may be the transition from water to land with one of the sides.

An array will consist of a number specifying the type of tile. 
I want to do it in python - for learning.

Some advice please.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no need to use recursion. Since you do this as a learning exercise, I will only provide you with an outline of how to progress.

The hexagonal grid will need a coordinate system, for the rows and columns.

Create a function `neighbours` that, given the coordinates x,y of a tile returns all the neighbours of that tile.

Loop through the all the tiles using your coordinate system. For each tile, retrieve its neighbours. If a neighbour does not have a type you can ignore it, otherwise, determine the character of a tile based on the character of its neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing is to denote your hexagons on the map in a way which makes checking neighbours easy...

One sensible choice could be to use 2D tuples, so that the hexagon (1,1)'s 6 neighbours are (1,0),(2,0),(2,2),(1,2),(0,2) and (1,1) - starting from north/up and going clockwise.

To populate the map you could then just iterate over all squares picking a random choice from the set of allowable tiles (based on it's current neighbours).

Answer (score 0):

Many, many years ago I implemented some hexmap routines.  I don't remember the details exactly, but I used a coordinate system such that each row was offset by 1 from the next.

Like this:

```
00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07
  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27
  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
```

So then you can find the coordinates of a hex's neighbors by applying these offsets to the hex's own coordinates (starting with the hex above and to the left, clockwise):

```
-1,-1  -1,0  0,1  1,0  1,-1  0,-1
```

So hex 24's neighbors are:
13, 14, 25, 34, 33, 24

You have to be aware of map edges, of course.